# React-native-agora Audio not working in foreground mode only in background mode (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, agora.io

I am facing a strange problem with RN agora, When I start a video call on iOS everything works fine but when
I pass my app to background and re-open it the audio doesn't work anymore in foreground mode.
Even if I end the call and join again the channel only background audio worked fine. I cannot understand why.

If someone could help please ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem:
I am using `react-native-video` for my welcomescreen background which is muted.
It is this prop : `ignoreSilentSwitch='obey'` which was causing the problem.
It can maybe help someone else.